# How do you append text to an input box using socket io inside html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I am having trouble at the moment trying to append text from inside my html.

```html
<input id="connection" type="text">
```

```js
socket.on('Connect',function(){
    console.out('testing blah');
    $('connection').val('con');
    $('connection').append("con");
    $('#connection').append('con');
});
```

I need a way of alerting the user that the server is available or not. I have tried all of the above examples and they all don't work correctly.

Comment: I seem to have "fixed" my problem by changing it to a label instead of a text input but I still want to understand why this fixed the problem.

Comment: have u tried $('#connection').val('con');

Comment: I think your problem is just wrong jQuery selectors. $('connection') selects every <connection></connection> element. Not <input id="connection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $('connection').val('con');

You missed the `#` prefix for the `id` selector

> $('connection').append("con");
>       $('#connection').append('con');

`append()` is invalid for `input` elements, and your first example is again missing the `#`.

Your first example, using `val()`, is the right way to achieve what you need, you just need to include the `#` in the selector:

```
$('#connection').val('con');
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code fixed my problem:

```
$('#connection').html('connected');
```

The reason I changed to html is because this clears the label instead of adding extra text to it.